# How to limit a package's dependency to a certain PHP version in Composer?

Tags: php, composer-php, package-managers, phpdotenv

Our production server is PHP `5.5.24`. A package I need (`vlucas/dotenv`) requires in its composer.json:

```
"symfony/polyfill-ctype": "^1.17"
```

Unfortunately version 1.20 of that symfony package requires 7.1, which causes Composer's platform check to fail. I cannot ignore the error/platform check because it results in a syntax error on PHP 5.5.

It seems that this does not work for sub-dependencies, just the package itself:

```
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "5.5.24"
    }
}
```

I've completely deleted the `vendor` folder and done a fresh install. Upgrading the server is not an option.

Comment: Can you just require `"symfony/polyfill-ctype": "1.17"` in your file which should version-lock that?

Comment: "Our production server is PHP 5.5.24" - that sounds like a horrible idea. 5.5.24 was released in April 2015, and PHP 5.5 hasn't seen any security updates since Jul 2016. Please plan to upgrade your servers

Comment: Preaching to the choir. We don't control the server, but thankfully this initiative is part of moving to the cloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just require an explicit version of a package without any additional constraints, and that will version-lock other dependencies.

Either manually add `"symfony/polyfill-ctype": "1.17"` to your composer.json file, or use `composer require symfony/polyfill-ctype:1.17` from the command line.

I will warn you that this might cause you headaches in the future when you upgrade, so make sure that you document it somewhere. Specifically, you or someone else in the future will look at the code and say "we aren't even using that", and then remove it.